# Aspiration in words beginning with h

Tags: prononciation, h-aspiré

My French teacher said that you would pronounce the "h" in words like *haut* and *hall*, that have an *h aspiré*. However, my previous French teacher said that the "h" aspiration does not exist at all in French. Which one is correct?

Answer (score 6):

In French, "h" is never pronounced like English /h/. It's always inaudible... but it can have an effect!

The « [h aspiré](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspirated_h) » is a phenomenon where a word starts with a [zero phoneme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_(linguistics)). Basically, **you have to pretend it starts with a consonant** even though you don't hear anything.

---

Why is that important? Because consonants affect how words run together.

For example, words that start with consonants don't allow [elision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elision#French). Neither does a word that starts with an « h aspiré » :

> **l'orange** mais **le pays** (*orange* starts with a vowel but *pays* starts with a consonant)
>
> **l'homme** mais **le héros** (*homme* has an « h muet » but *héros* has an « h aspiré »)

Words that start with consonants also don't allow [liaison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liaison_(French)). Neither does a word that starts with an « h aspiré » :

> **cet orange** mais **ce pays**
>
> **cet homme** mais **ce héros**

There are other similar alternations, but hopefully these examples make the pattern clear.

---

How do you tell whether a word has an « h aspiré » or an « h muet » ?

The Wikipedia article lists some ideas, though nothing is failsafe and most are hard to do on the fly. For example, it says that Germanic words tend to have an « h aspiré » while Latinate words have an « h muet ». But how do you know which words are Germanic if you're not a linguist?

The failsafe way is to check a dictionary (as usual), where it will be marked in the pronunciation.

For example, here's the WordReference pronunciation for *[homme](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/homme)* with its « h muet ». Notice how the first symbol is a vowel:

> /ɔm/

But here's the pronunciation for « héros » with its « h aspiré ». Notice that the first symbol is an apostrophe:

> /ˈeʀo/

Comment: I'll want to add that it also affects liaison. "*un homme*" is pronounced /ɛ̃ nɔm/ while "*un héros*" is pronounced "ɛ̃ 'eʀo/.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Luke answer which clearly explains the *h aspiré* issue, note that despite the fact the letter "h" is never pronounced and thus that there is no [h] consonant listed in the phonetic French alphabet, the sound [h] can nevertheless be heard in spoken French without relationship between the presence or not of the letter "h", especially at the beginning of sentences with a stressed first vowel.

For example, the sentence:

> Et alors ?

is sometimes pronounced with a leading [h], \ **he** alɔʁ \ instead of \ **e** alɔʁ \

We make no distinction between the variants.

That also explain why the French accent often mix up words like "**and** " and "**hand**", "**to heat**" and "**to eat**"...

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Thanks.